# How do I change between read and write files in C

Tags: c

my question is as follows:

For school I have to make a little program in C to create and modify .txt files. I have gotten to create the file and write on it but when I read from it to print on the screen It doesn't do from the beginning and then the "fisical" file in my computer is all corrupted with chinese characters...

I don't know what's going on... Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 1

void clrscr()
{
    system("cls");
}

int getLenght(char *Rstring)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(Rstring[n] != '\0')
        n++;
    return n;
}

void getPath(char fname[])
{
    printf("Insert file path: ");
    gets(fname);
    fflush(stdin);
}

// Returns 0 DOESNT EXIST, 1 DOES EXIST
int fileExist(char *fname)
{
    if(access(fname, F_OK) != -1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//if manage file is NULL truncate program
FILE *manageFile(char *fname)
{
    if(fileExist(fname))
        return fopen(fname, "r+");
    else
        return fopen(fname, "w+");
}

//Returns 1 if there's an ERROR 0 if NOT
int readFile(FILE *streamf, char buffer[])
{
    fflush(streamf);
    fseek(streamf, -1, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, SIZE, sizeof(buffer), streamf);
    if(ferror(streamf)){
        clearerr(streamf);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Returns 1 if there's an ERROR 0 if NOT
int writeFile(FILE *streamf, char buffer[])
{
    int NELEMT;
    printf("Insert text to input file:\n");
    gets(buffer);
    fflush(stdin);
    NELEMT = getLenght(buffer);
    fflush(streamf);
    fseek(streamf, 1, SEEK_END);
    fwrite(buffer, SIZE, NELEMT, streamf);
    if(ferror(streamf)){
        clearerr(streamf);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char fname[1000];
    char buffer[1000];
    char choice;
    int CC = 1;
    FILE *streamf = NULL;

    printf("\tFILE MANAGMENT SYSTEM TEST v 1.0\n");
    getPath(fname);
    streamf = manageFile(fname);
    if(streamf == NULL){
        printf("\n\nFILE OPEN ERROR! Terminate Program");
        CC = 0;
    }

    while(CC == 1){
        clrscr();
        printf("\tFILE MANAGMENT SYSTEM TEST v 1.0 - MENU\nCURRENT PATH: %s\n\n", fname);
        printf("1. Read File\n2. Write File\n3. Close File\n");
        choice = getch();
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(choice)
        {
        case '1':
            if(readFile(streamf, buffer))
                printf("\n\nREAD FILE ERROR!");
            else
                printf("Successfully read from the file:\n%s", buffer);
            getch();
            break;
        case '2':
            if(writeFile(streamf, buffer))
                printf("\n\nWRITE FILE ERROR!");
            else
                printf("Successful file input");
            getch();
            break;
        case '3':
            fflush(streamf);
            fclose(streamf);
            CC = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n\nOPTION NOT LISTED");
            getch();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: And checking for a file before opening is invitation to race-conditions. Just open and handle the error if it fails. In general: **always** check the result of functions which can encounter an error.

Comment: Instead of posting a wall of code, could you narrow it down to just a few lines that are giving you problems?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `sizeof(buffer)` in the call to `fread` but it's not doing what you think.  Look at how you pass `buffer` into `readFile`:

```
int readFile( FILE *streamf, char buffer[] );
```

This means that `buffer` is just a pointer, and so `sizeof(buffer)` will be equal to `sizeof(char*)`.  It's a classic mistake people make with `sizeof` so this is a rite of passage for you.

You will need to actually pass in a size to your function, or redefine it to accept `char buffer[1000]`.  I would pass a size explicitly though:

```
int readFile( FILE *streamf, char buffer[], size_t buffer_size );
```

Also, as appeared in the comments, you are using `fseek` incorrectly.  You need to use an offset of `0` with both `SEEK_SET` and `SEEK_END`.